# Can I query Firestore based on a value in a subArray?

Tags: arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Trucks collection in Firestore. Each truck in the collection has an array of 1 or more Schedule objects. Each Schedule object has a longitude field with a value.

I would like to query whether a truck's scheduled longitude is between two values as in:

```
        let trucksRef = db.collection("trucks")
        let sw = bounds.southWest
        let ne = bounds.northEast
        
        //get the trucks between 2 latitude lines (Firestore will only allow "inequality where" clauses on the same field)
        trucksRef
            .whereField("schedules[0].lon", isGreaterThan: sw.longitude)
            .whereField("schedules[0].lon", isLessThan: ne.longitude)
```

The above code crashes so it is obviously wrong. In my research, it seems as if it is not possible to query into the schedules array like this. Looking for confirmation on that assumption and also possible solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a way to index into array field items for queries, so there is no `[0]` or equivalent.  You will need an alternative way to model your data.

If you are only ever interested in the first item in the array for this query, you could copy the longitude into top-level fields.

If you are interested in an unknown number of longitude values, it's not going to be possible to consider them all in a single document.  You should move the schedule items to individual documents in a subcolletion, then query that subcollection as needed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured as much. I have considered your first option, and, as a matter of fact, it was my original solution. If I implement your second solution, I guess I could look for all schedules that are between my longitude values, get the truckIDs from there and then query for all trucks with those ids? Hmmm... maybe worth trying to see what the performance is like.  Thank you!

Comment: That sounds like a possibility, yes.